# Update campaign in mailchimp v 2.0 using php

Tags: php, mailchimp

Just wondering why my code is not working since I follow all the documentation

here's my code

```
require('mailchimp/Mailchimp.php');
require('../constant.php');

$api_key = MAIL_CHIMP_API_KEY;
$list_id = MAIL_CHIMP_AUD_ID;

$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Campaigns = new Mailchimp_Campaigns( $Mailchimp );

$segment_opts = array(
    'match' => 'any',
    'conditions' => array (
        array(
            'field' => 'interests-196994',
            'op' => 'all',
            'value' => array ( 'DEV')
        )
    )
);
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Campaigns->update('100bf85c64','segment_opts',$segment_opts);
```

Is this the correct syntax for mailchimp v 2.0?

Here's my error code:

Fatal error: Uncaught Mailchimp_List_InvalidInterestGroup: "DEV" is not a valid Interest Bit for the list: TestWeb - Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 16 [2] => 32 [3] => 64 [4] => 128 [5] => 256 [6] => 512 [7] => 1024 [8] => 2048 [9] => 4096 )